# Animating window scrolling

Tags: javascript, animation, scroll

Hi
I am using the following method to programmatically scroll a web document:

```
window.scrollBy(0, delta)
```

The current implementation of scrollBy just jumps the document to the new position.  Is there a way of animating this?  I am using webkit specifically, and jQuery (or any other javascript framework) is not an option.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Whatever your reasons are for reinventing the wheel, you can still look at how the established frameworks implement smooth animations, and learn from that, no?

Comment: @Thomas: Since Webkit offers CSS animations with easing, it is not implausible to think that a similar native mechanism might be available for scrolling (which is not the case AFAIK)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can just animate it by invoking an interval:

```
setInterval(function() {
    window.scrollBy(0, 5);
}, 13);
```

This of course would do it over and over, so you need to put in a conditional check, when to cancel the interval. Could look like:

```
var timerID = setInterval(function() {
    window.scrollBy(0, 5);

    if( window.pageYOffset >= 500 )
        clearInterval(timerID);
}, 13);
```

Comment: Cool, best solution so far.  I was hoping for something a bit more sophisticated like ease-in-ease-out.

Comment: @darren: I'm afraid vanilla javascript won't offer easings. That is on your own.

Comment: I was ideally hoping there was a hidden webkit transform that I could apply to the window.scrollBy stuff :)

Comment: In what way can I change this so that it starts scrolling after say 1second?

Comment: wrap it with `setTimeout(function(){ //setInterval code here }, 1000);`

Answer (score 0):

Every time this function is called, it will jump the number of pixels in window.scrollBy (0,5), regardless of where the pageYOffset is. For instance, if pageYOffset is 300px, it will jump to 305px.

but this problem can be solved by moving the if and adding an else

like so:

```
var timerID = setInterval(function() {
    if( window.pageYOffset <= 500 )
        window.scrollBy(0, 5);

    else
        clearInterval(timerID);
}, 1);
```